# Autofac Webforms is there away to ignore postback dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, autofac

I am maintaining companies very old website (WebForms) and it is using Autofac as Dependency Injection.

One of the issues I have is that every time Page_Load is called, any dependencies are resolved again setting them to new. How can I stop this?

Don't have code at hand right now but this example should explain better

Example case

```
public class DatabaseManager
{
    public string CustomerDbConnection {get;set;}
}

public partial class SiteSetup: Page
{
    public DatabaseManager dbManager {get;set;}

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           // blah blah
        }

    }

    protected void DdlDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dbManager.CustomerDbConnection  = "Some db connection";
    }

    protected void ImageSaveSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // Do something with dbManager.CustomerDbConnection
    }
}
```

So in the above, DatabaseManager is injected into SiteSetup page. When the user selects an item in a dropdown list box 'DdlDatabase', the 'dbManager.CustomerDbConnection' is set.

If the user then clicks on a button, 'ImageSaveSite', then I get an exception when trying to access 'dbManager.CustomerDbConnection' because it is null.

Put a breakpoint in the 'Page_OnLoad' method and I can see every time it is called I can see 'dbManager.CustomerDbConnection' is null. I can only assume that a new instance of 'DatabaseManager' is being resolved.

Is there a way of preventing this? I was thinking about registering DatabaseManager as a singleton but then wouldn't every user of the website be accessing the same instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of how WebForms lifecycle works I recommend slightly different solution with use of `ViewState`

If you want to have some communication between *postbacks* you need to persist it in `ViewState`. But connection is not serializable. So I used helper property `ConnectionIdentifier` for keeping selected Identifier.

```
public string ConnectionIdentifier
{
     get => ViewState[nameof(ConnectionIdentifier)] as string;
     set => ViewState[nameof(ConnectionIdentifier)] = value;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
       // blah blah
    }       
}

protected void DdlDatabase_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ConnectionIdentifier = "Selected db identifier";
}

protected void ImageSaveSite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ConnectionIdentifier != null){
        //not really needed depending on your UI

        dbManager.CustomerDbConnection = ConnectionIdentifier; //processing identifier
    }
   
}
```

Comment: hmmm its something to consider. DatabaseManager is a lot more complex than what I provided so not sure how well I can convert to using ViewState. Suppose the other option is to strip all methods from DatabaseManager and move to a separate class.

Comment: @Gaz83 yes question is how much do you really need to initialize in different postback event. Maintaining the 'state' is always difficult. No matter the application technology.

Comment: Well basically there is say 12 different databases. 1 for the main website and the rest are customer databases. Through the main website, you can interact with various customer databases. Most pages you have to select a database from a dropdown which reveals the rest of the page controls. Remembering the selected connection here is key. It seems to be stored in database manager. This use to be static but that caused other issues. I might have to rethink the database manager.

Comment: @Gaz83 this selected DB has some identifier which could be used and stored in ViewState? and then used for initialization.

Comment: Yeah thats what I am thinking. The connection string can go in a viewstate